# Download a file from web api via mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have a published api route that's returning a Task.  From a completely separate site I'm trying to hit the route, get the stream, and save the contents to a file local to the system that's accessing the site.  From a test console application that's hitting the route I get the stream just fine and can do whatever I want with it.  But from my separate MVC controller, when stepping through, after hitting the route and waiting for the Result my page just appears to stop.  Stepping through it just does nothing after stepping over that line.  How do I get around this?

Sorry, I forgot we abstracted away a lot of the details that may be important.

The GetStream method is basically just

```
return (new HttpClient()).GetStreamAsync(route);  //where route is the route to my api method
```

And the method behind my route has this

```
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            return result;
```

The Method in the mvc controller is

```
public FileResult DownloadLogFile([Bind(Include = "SelectedLogFile")] DiagnosticsModel diagnostics)
    {
        using (var downStream = GetStream())
        {
            return new FileStreamResult(downStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        }
    }

private Stream GetStream()
{
    var apiResult = api.GetStream();
    return apiResult.Result;
}
```

Comment: How did you acess this API? HttpClient?

Comment: @Fals Yes, it's via an HttpCient

Comment: You should provide more code, this one above can't help us to find out what's happen

Comment: @Fals Editing as you were responding